# Image magick to put images in row and then generate reflection

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I was wondering if I can use imagemagick to produce a result image like this

[image]

My initial image will be like this

[image]

I am able to create the dark image to be put in the background like this -

```
convert -brightness-contrast -20x10 GARDENS-ILLUSTRATED_JAN-14.jpg out_lighter2.jpg
```

But I do not know how to put them in line like that and then generate a reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got something close, but have no more time, so maybe you can fiddle with it and get it to what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
input=input.png

# Calculate width and height
w=$(convert $input -ping -format "%w" info:)
h=$(convert $input -ping -format "%h" info:)

# Calculate how much to chop off bottom and height of reflection
chop=$(echo $h*60/100|bc)
refl=$(echo $h*20/100|bc)
convert $input -alpha on \
      \( +clone -flip -size ${w}x${refl} gradient:gray40-black -alpha off -compose CopyOpacity -composite \) \
      -append -background white -compose Over -flatten -gravity South -chop 0x${chop} output1.png

# Darken and reduce for second layer
convert output1.png -brightness-contrast -25x8 -resize 90% output2.png

# Darken and reduce for third layer
convert output2.png -brightness-contrast -25x8 -resize 90% output3.png

# Make big new output canvas
neww=$(echo $w*1.6|bc)
newh=$(echo $h*1.6|bc)

# Splat images onto it with offsets
convert -size ${neww}x${newh} xc:transparent -page +0+80 output3.png \
    -page +40+40 output2.png \
    -page +80+0 output1.png -flatten output.png
```

My basic idea is to generate the bright, frontmost image first in `output1.png`, then darken and reduce it into `output2.png` and again into `output3.png`. Then composite them all together into `output.png` with a little offset.

[image]

Comment: @Mark, I cannot ask for more precise solution. Thanks a lot.